# How do I display Chinese text properly in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, chinese-locale

I'm Chinese, and deal with Chinese characters frequently. I still can't find a way to properly encode Chinese.

The best way so far is `read.csv(file_name, fileEncoding = "UTF8")`. But when I list all the files in the `wd` using `dir()`, it comes up garbled:

```
> dir()
[1] "16PF.csv"       "codebook.html"  "Table_2.xls"   
[4] "win-library"    "鏈牎鏂囩.csv" "鏈牎鏂囩.R"
```

This is after I set the system locale:

```
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs") #cht for traditional Chinese, etc.
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936"
```

In `Global Options` -> `Code` -> `Saving`, the default encoding is set to UTF8.

I also wish to make R Studio read Chinese text, without having to use a command every time I open it.

**Update**：the method provided by @niki is good for simple text reading: https://imgur.com/a/6XtwmzC

However, I need to deal with Chinese characters in data frames.

I just discovered that `read.csv(file_name, fileEncoding = "UTF8")` actually doesn't work:

```
> grades=read.csv("grades.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-8")
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'grades.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'grades.csv'
```

Unless I set the system locale:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936"
> grades=read.csv("grades.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-8")
> head(grades[,c(3,6,8)],3)
  文理类型 学生类型 数学
1     文科     应届  138
2     文科     应届  134
3     文科     应届  119
```

Because it's cumbersome to set system locale every time I start R Studio, I tried to put `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")` in `Rprofile`, but it didn't seem to work.

**Update 2:** I seem to have located the wrong `RProfile` file. It has now been resolved.